# Build chromium in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, chromium

I'm following [The Chromium Projects](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code) to build chromium browser on Windows. When I go to **Run post-sync hooks** step and run

```
gclient runhooks
```

The following errors show,

```
________ running     'D:\Chromium\depot_tools\depot_tools\python276_bin\python.exe src/build/landmines.py' in 'D:\Chromium\chromium'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/build/landmines.py", line 147, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
  File "src/build/landmines.py", line 134, in main
gyp_environment.SetEnvironment()
  File "D:\Chromium\chromium\src\build\gyp_environment.py", line 33, in SetEnvironment
vs_toolchain.SetEnvironmentAndGetRuntimeDllDirs()
  File "D:\Chromium\chromium\src\build\vs_toolchain.py", line 73, in SetEnvironmentAndGetRuntimeDllDirs
os.environ['GYP_MSVS_OVERRIDE_PATH'] = DetectVisualStudioPath()
  File "D:\Chromium\chromium\src\build\vs_toolchain.py", line 139, in DetectVisualStudioPath
' not found.') % (version_as_year))
Exception: Visual Studio Version 2013 (from GYP_MSVS_VERSION) not found.
Error: Command 'D:\\Chromium\\depot_tools\\depot_tools\\python276_bin\\python.exe src/build/landmines.py' returned non-zero exit status 1 in D:\Chromium\chromium
```

My visual studio version is 2015 and from the errors above, it seems vs 2013 is not found. Does anyone know how can I build with vs 2015? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Updated (12/13/2016):

As it states in [chromium instruction](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/windows_build_instructions.md), the previous answer may not work any more. Please take care!

> As of December 8, 2016 Chromium requires Visual Studio 2015, with the 14393 Windows SDK to build.

### Previous:

Solved this problem by the following command

```
set GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2015
```

More details can be tracked in the [chromium discuss](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-discuss/3gvr-YaDULE)

Comment: So did you successfully build Chromium and all the dependencies from VS without using ninja? Debugging should be much more easier if we build it from VS

Answer (score 1):

WebRTC (v62) **doesn't works** with Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise.

Be careful and look at vs_toolchain.py from row 149

```
if version_as_year == '2017':
    # The VC++ 2017 install location needs to be located using COM instead of
    # the registry. For details see:
    # https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2016/09/15/changes-to-visual-studio-15-setup/
    # For now we use a hardcoded default with an environment variable override.
    for path in (
        os.environ.get('vs2017_install'),
        r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional',
        r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community'):
      if path and os.path.exists(path):
        return path
```